# How to remove a row from the Cell Table

Tags: java, gwt

At first I used the Grid.
After creating a new version of the GWT, I want to replace the Grid on the CellTable.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are asking.  Can you provide some code examples or expand your description?

Comment: I can't find a method to remove row in CellTable class like "removeRow(int rowNum)" in Grid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) for details. My example is like the one you'll find there (just a little extended):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final CellTable<Row> table = new CellTable<Row>();

    TextColumn<Row> firstColumn = new TextColumn<Starter.Row>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Row object) {
            return object.firstColumn;
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(firstColumn, "header one");

    TextColumn<Row> secondColumn = new TextColumn<Starter.Row>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Row object) {
            return object.secondColumn;
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(secondColumn, "header two");

    TextColumn<Row> thirdColumn = new TextColumn<Starter.Row>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Row object) {
            return object.thirdColumn;
        }
    };
    table.addColumn(thirdColumn, "header three");

    table.setRowCount(getList().size());
    final ListDataProvider<Row> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Starter.Row>(getList());
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

    final SingleSelectionModel<Row> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Starter.Row>();
    table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);

    Button btn = new Button("delete entry");
    btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Row selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
            if (selected != null) {
                dataProvider.getList().remove(selected);
            }
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(table);
    RootPanel.get().add(btn);

}

private class Row {

    private String firstColumn;
    private String secondColumn;
    private String thirdColumn;

    public Row(String firstColumn, String secondColumn, String thirdColumn) {
        this.firstColumn = firstColumn;
        this.secondColumn = secondColumn;
        this.thirdColumn = thirdColumn;
    }

}

private LinkedList<Row> getList() {
    LinkedList<Row> list = new LinkedList<Row>();
    list.add(new Row("first", "entry", "foo"));
    list.add(new Row("second", "entry", "foo"));
    list.add(new Row("third", "entry", "foo"));
    list.add(new Row("fourth", "entry", "foo"));
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just run the cycle like that

```
@UiHandler("combo") 
public void onChange(ChangeEvent e) {
    textBoxes.clear();
    searchFields.clear();
    while(resultsTable.getColumnCount()!=0) {
        resultsTable.removeColumn(0);
    }
    resultsTable.redraw();
```

Where resultsTable is a CellTable

Answer (score 1):

CellTable as part of new [DataPresentationWidgets](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html) used just to display data. So you should delete according member from list of data which CellTable using to display.